# symbolic-link in JDK cannot be promoted to source control, any risk?

Tags: java, accurev

When I try to promote latest JDK into our source control (AccuRev), I get the following error:

**jdk/bin/ControlPanel':  Element is a symbolic-link on disk, should be a file or directory.**

This is NOT the only symbolic-link in the latest 1.7.0_51 JDK. I didn't have this issue in 1.7.0_09.

Above symbolic-link points to a file under the same directory. I am using Linux.

Is there any risk with those symbolic-link for product (**jre** folder has the same symbolic-link and reports the same error)?

**EDIT:**

here is another one:

**jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so':  Element is a symbolic-link on disk, should be a file or directory.**

**EDIT2:**

**[XXXXXX server]$ accurev stat -fix libjsig.so**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcResponse
    Command="stat"
    Directory="/XXXXXX/3rdparty/java/linux/64bit/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server"
    TaskId="450242">
  <element
      location="/./XXXXX/3rdparty/java/linux/64bit/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so"
      dir="no"
      executable="yes"
      id="12936"
      elemType="binary"
      size="13"
      modTime="1394570292"
      hierType="parallel"
      Virtual="1/1"
      namedVersion="XXXXX/1"
      Real="269/1"
      status="(modified)"/>
</AcResponse>
```

**[XXXXX server]$ accurev**

```
AccuRev 5.4.1 (2012/02/28)
Copyright (c) 1995-2012 AccuRev Inc. All rights reserved
type 'accurev help' for help.
```

**[XXXXX server]$ ls -l libjsig.so**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 XXX XXX 13 Mar 11 16:38 libjsig.so -> ../libjsig.so
```

Comment: Why do you keep binary distributions in your source control?

Comment: shared with other engineers and everybody use the same dev environment. and different projects use different versions, we have very old project, still in JDK 1.4.

Comment: `I didn't have this issue in 1.7.0_09` - at least for `1.7.0_05`, these were also symbolic links. Are you sure that you have verified with a vanilla `1.7.0_09`?

Comment: I checked with my old dev setting and installed product. They are 1.7.0_09 and they have the same files. My co-worker just started to help me a week ago with that setting with no problem. I was trying to update the JDK this morning and found above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are these files currently external in your workspace and you are doing a promote from your workspace?

If they are external, I might suggest you run the command 'accurev add -x -s" from within this workspace and then promote those files.  The -s switch forces all symbolic link objects (at the OS level) whose targets are
within the current workspace to be converted to symbolic-link elements (at the AccuRev level).

Comment: They are showing as modified but cannot be "keep" and "promote".

Comment: What is the output from the following command?  "accurev keep -c "some comment" -m"

Comment: Cannot keep '/XXXXXXXX/3rdparty/java/linux/64bit/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so':
  Element is a symbolic-link on disk, should be a file or directory.

Comment: Can you also include the following output?  Please run these commands from within the directory /XXXXXXXX/3rdparty/java/linux/64bit/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server.  "accurev stat -fix libjsig.so", "accurev" and "ls -l libjsig.so"

Comment: please have a look at my original post at EDIT2. Thanks

Comment: What is interesting is this file is a symlink on disk but AccuRev is saying the element type is binary...elemType="binary"...I would have expected to see elemType="slink" or elemType="elink".  I would try performing the following commands:  "accurev mv libjsig.so libjsig.so.badLink", "accurev ln -s ../libjsig.so libjsig.so"....This should create an accurev symbolic link, once you have confirmed this, you can then defunct the bad link, "accurev defunct -c "remove bad link" libjsig.so"